# AndroidBiometricPrompt onAuthenticationError returns wrong error

Tags: android, android-biometric-prompt

I implemented the new **androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.1** as described [here](https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/biometric-auth#display-login-prompt) and using **setDeviceCredentialAllowed(true)**. On API 29 it works correctly, on API < 29 when there aren't any device credentials set I would expect to get **ERROR_NO_DEVICE_CREDENTIAL** but I'm getting **ERROR_USER_CANCELED**, is this a library bug and if yes where can I report this? or if no what am I missing?

Since the documenation says this library is backwards compatible I would expect I don't need to handle anything myself for API<29, right?

As I could see in the BiometricPrompt.java there is a code-block:

```
        case DeviceCredentialHandlerBridge.RESULT_ERROR:
            // Device credential auth failed. Assume this is due to the user canceling.
            final CharSequence errorMsg = getActivity() != null
                    ? getActivity().getString(R.string.generic_error_user_canceled) : "";
            mAuthenticationCallback.onAuthenticationError(
                    BiometricConstants.ERROR_USER_CANCELED, errorMsg);
            bridge.stopIgnoringReset();
            bridge.reset();
            break;
```

Don't know further though.

Comment: Can you provide source link of this class? I don't see such code block here https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/hardware/biometrics/BiometricPrompt.java

Comment: Also, looking at documentation seems like it treats API < 28 same as FingerprintManager. https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/biometric/BiometricPrompt

Comment: androidx.biometric.BiometricPrompt line 925 https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/biometric/biometric/src/main/java/androidx/biometric/BiometricPrompt.java